# how to intstall mcpack in minecraft programatically android

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

i'm trying to send (install) my mcpack file using this code but is is not working, minecraft support this type of extenstion to install mods (.mcpack, .mcaddon, .mcworld, .mctemplate, .modpkg how we can define mimetypes for these extensions)

please go through this image i need exactly like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sIJf.jpg

```
 try {
    //File path = new File(getFilesDir(), "dl");
    File file = new File(path);
    PackageManager manager = this.getPackageManager();
    // Get URI and MIME type of file
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    //share.setType("image/jpeg");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(path));
    share.setPackage("com.mojang.minecraftpe");//package name of the app
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select Minecraft to install"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.i(TAG, "App not found.. "+e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

i did it!)

```
            File file = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "1.mcpack");
        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
// set the content type and data of the intent
        intent.setDataAndType(photoURI, "application/octet-stream");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
// start the intent as a new activity
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Open with minecraft and it will open and it will day download started and if it works it will say, If it does not work it will say, Minecraft onlu supports .mcpack, .mcworld, .mctemplate on pocket edition

Comment: how can we perform this action

Comment: You need to install minecraft from the official device store, Not a apk, If you are using the official minecraft and its not working try to download the game again and if that does not work you may need to reset your device incase you deleted an file.